TYPO3 TypoScript in Backend for multidomain usage (v13)
Since TYPO3 v12 ive used this code to get the TypoScript from the actual page
$configurationManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Configuration\\BackendConfigurationManager');
$configurationManager->currentPageId = $pageId;
$extbaseFrameworkConfiguration = $configurationManager->getTypoScriptSetup();
return $extbaseFrameworkConfiguration;

Now that the BackendConfigurationManager is declared as final in v13 i can't set the page id.
I've tried this
$configurationManager = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(ConfigurationManagerInterface::class);
$typoScript = $configurationManager->getConfiguration(ConfigurationManagerInterface::CONFIGURATION_TYPE_FULL_TYPOSCRIPT);

But the result is following error:
Setup array has not been initialized. This happens in cached Frontend scope where full TypoScript is not needed by the system.
I need the TypoScipt here. My class doesn't extends a controller. i use a simple own class.
The code is used in a custom class in my extbase extension.

Please give more information: Where is the code executed (maybe custom backend module)? What are you trying to achieve (in terms of: I need something to do this and that).
Addition: Also, as you use the BackendConfigurationManager: TypoScript is only available in frontend context. In backend you have to bootstrap everything yourself. Maybe page TSconfig is a possibility then?

Why are you double posting? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78997125/typo3-extend-final-classes

This question is similar to: TYPO3 extend final classes. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
